# zoom out in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, zooming

When you double tap on MKMapView : zoom in.

But how to zoom out??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's always using two fingers to zoom in and out.  On the emulator you need to hold down an option key to get 'two fingers' appear on the emulated screen (I think it's the Alt key but I use a PC keyboard on my mac so may differ on a real mac keyboard)

As for doing it procedurally you need to set the region on the mapkit.
via the `setRegion` method of your `MKMapKit` object.

Make sure you're within bounds though as it will cause a crash if not.  (i.e. long -180

Comment: thanksssss
worked for me.
so it will zoom in n zoom out with two finger in device...okyeee